# Changing div inner HTML content by id in angular component method

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am trying to change inner HTML content of a div by id with another div in angular component method. I am able to call `populateEndpointHomeContent()` and get that content but not further content. Actually those methods `populateAddEndpoint()` and `populateAddEndpointForm` are not getting called on click. I am not getting any console error also. Any idea how I can get this?

endpoint.component.html

```
<div id="endpoint_home"></div>

<div id="endpoint_home_content" style="display:none">
    <button class="btn btn-sm" (click)="populateAddEndpoint();">+ Add Endpoint</button>
</div>

<!-- Add Endpoint DIVS Starts -->
<div id="add_endpoint_home" style="display:none">
    <form #endpointForm="ngForm">
        <section class="form-block">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="endPointType">Select Endpoint Type</label>
                <div class="select">
                    <select id="endPointType" (change)="populateAddEndpointForm(this.value);">
                        <option>MACHINE</option>
                        <option>K8S_CLUSTER</option>
                        <option>AWS</option>
                        <option>DOCKER</option>
                        <option>VCENTER</option>
                        <option>WAVEFRONT</option>
                        <option>VRNI</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="add_endpoint_form"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
        </section>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="add_machine_form" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" size="42" id="name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="credentialsName">Credential Name</label>
        <div class="select">
            <select id="credentialsName">
                <option>MACHINE</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ADD CREDENTIAL</button>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="host">Machine Host/IP</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="0.0.0.0" size="42" id="host" name="host" [(ngModel)]="host" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="sshPort">SSH Port</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="22" size="42" id="sshPort" name="sshPort" [(ngModel)]="sshPort" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="timeout">SSH Timeout</label>
        <input type="number" placeholder="60" size="42" id="timeout" name="timeout" [(ngModel)]="timeout" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="osType">OS Type</label>
        <div class="select">
            <select id="osType">
                <option>WINDOWS</option>
                <option>LINUX</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Add Endpoint DIVS Ends -->
```

EndpointComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EndpointService } from './endpoint.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-endpoint',
  templateUrl: './endpoint.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./endpoint.component.scss']
})
export class EndpointComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private endpointService: EndpointService) { }

  public wavefrontendpoints: any;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.populateEndpointHomeContent();
      this.endpointService.getAllEndpoints().subscribe(res => this.wavefrontendpoints = res.response[0]);
  }

    public populateEndpointHomeContent() {
        document.getElementById('endpoint_home').innerHTML = document.getElementById('endpoint_home_content').innerHTML;
    }

    public populateAddEndpoint() {
      console.log('Inside populateAddEndpoint...');
      document.getElementById('endpoint_home').innerHTML = document.getElementById('add_endpoint_home').innerHTML;
    }

  public populateAddEndpointForm(endPointType) {
      console.log('Inside populateAddEndpointForm...');
      if(endPointType === 'MACHINE') { document.getElementById('add_endpoint_form').innerHTML = document.getElementById('add_machine_form').innerHTML; }

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try the inner html directive?
<div [innerHTML]="content"></div?

Comment: Pls! I don't want to try this one.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to render HTML content from its innerHTML will not have its prototype functions work.

Your HTML will be visible, but it won't make their click events trigger, because innerHTML only contains the HTML markup, not the function or event prototypes.

Go through Angular's Guide on [Dynamic Component Loader](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader), which is about loading dynamic content in an HTML page.